# Calling a constructor without hard coding parameters (coupling)

Tags: java

I have a method which creates a new object Student and adds it to an array list studentRegister:

```
public void addStudent(String name, String age)
{
     studentRegister.add(new Student(name, age));
}
```

it calls the Student class constructor here:

```
public Student(String name, String age) 
{
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
```

This works but it is bad for maintainability as i have to change any additional parameters in both the Student class and the addStudent method. How do I input the parameters at the addStudent stage without having them harcoded in the addStudent method?

Comment: Make the `addStudent` method take a `Student` parameter.

Comment: Where is the `addStudent` method defined?

Comment: [Another reason why C# is better than java](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just do this:

```
public void addStudent(Student s)
{
     studentRegister.add(s);
}
```

And in constructer/ other methods you can call the above method as below:

```
public Student(String name, String age) 
{
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  addStudent(this); //here is the call to the above method
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should pass a student object - Instead of the two values.

```
public void addStudent(Student student)
{
     studentRegister.add(student);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
public void addStudent(final Student student) {
    studentRegister.add(student);
}
```

is the better aproach.

Maybe you're looking for a simpler way to build the object. e.g. using chain setters:

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Student setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public Student setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
        return this;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public Student setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
        return this;
    }
}
```

So, would then:

```
Student student = new Student().setName("User")
                               .setAge("30")
                               .setAddress("New York");
```

Another way for build the object with normal setters:

```
Student student = new Student(){{
    setName("User");
    setAge("30");
    setAddress("30");
}};
```